# Can data be piped dynamically into Excel or Google Spreadsheet fields?

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, google-docs

Is it possible to add dynamically loaded data to a spreadsheet field in either Excel or Google Spreadsheets that retrieves it's value from an externally referenced data source such as a Yahoo Data Pipe or an AJAX response?

If so, is it possible to make the data "live" so it updates at regular polling intervals?

Comment: The answer to both questions (at least for Excel) is yes.

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek Would you please post how to do this as an answer to the question?

Comment: @eComEvo Mitja may be referring to your poorly asked question. Technically, the answer is `Yes`. If you would like to know how, try providing some more information about what you have tried, how your data is structured, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For Google Spreadsheets, use [importData](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335) by writing the following in a spreadsheet cell:

```
=importDATA("http://www.census.gov/2010census/csv/pop_change.csv")
```